# How do I delete a personal canvas in darklang?

Tags: darklang-beta

I've created several canvases in the Dark UI. Just for housekeeping, how do I remove canvases I'm no longer using? I've found the canvases listed under the Account/Canvases modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dark doesn't currently support deleting a canvas.

Comment: That's fine, it's early stages of development for darklang I know. Hopefully if anyone else has this question they'll find this answer without needing to ask on the darklang Slack channel.